# MoleculeModify not working in Mathematica 13.1

Tags: bugs, chemistry

This question is related to [an older question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264530/moleculemodifydeleteatom-a-behaving-strangely), which was acknowledged to have uncovered a bug.

Unlike in the previous question, this time I am not trying to delete a hydrogen atom. But in `Mathematica 13.1` I still get an unevaluated expression back for `MoleculeModify[{"DeleteAtom", idx}]`:

```
ClearAll[mol];
mol = Molecule[
    "Cc1ccc2c(NC(=O)c3cc4c([nH]c3=O)CC(C)(C3CC(N5CC(N(C)C(=O)c6cccc(OCC(=O)O)c6)C5=O)C3)CC4=O)cc(=O)cc2c1",
    IncludeHydrogens -> All
];

MoleculePlot[mol, {28}]
```

[image: Plot of mol]

```
(* Mathematica 13.1 *)
mol // MoleculeModify[{"DeleteAtom", 28}]
(* Output: unevaluated expression *)
```

But `Mathematica 13.0.1` returns the correct molecule components:

```
(* Mathematica 13.0.1 *)
mol // (
    MoleculeModify[{"DeleteAtom", 28}] /*
    ConnectedMoleculeComponents /*
    Map[MoleculePlot] /*
    Column
)
```

[image: Components of mol after the deletion of atom 28]

`MoleculeModify` is not one of the functions for which [incompatible changes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html) have been announced. Does this mean this is a bug? Is there a workaround? (It is affecting me quite severely.)

Comment: This is a bug, seems to happen with invalid SMILES strings with bad aromaticity.  As a workaround use `Molecule["Cc1ccc2c(NC(=O)c3cc4c([nH]c3=O)CC(C)(C3CC(N5CC(N(C)C(=O)c6cccc(OCC(=O)O)c6)C5=O)C3)CC4=O)cc(=O)cc2c1",IncludeAromaticBonds->False]` when dealing with bad SMILES strings like this one